# Correlation between curves and moving along the x axes in R

Tags: r

I am trying to correct some curves. The main idea is to focus on one curve and move the other curves along the X axes until all match. I have written a script with first attempts. But my script is inefficient, I must move every single curve with plotting and correction by manually. Is there a package that detects the correlation between the curves and automatically shifts the signals along the x-axes?

Data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xneq9oi796t3lk/Test2.csv?dl=0

best

```
library(ggplot2)

Alles <- read.csv("Test2.csv")
Alles <- Alles[c(1:106)]

Eins <- Alles[,c(1,2)]
Zwei <- Alles[,c(3,4)]
Drei <- Alles[,c(5,6)]
Vier <- Alles[,c(7,8)]
Funf <- Alles[,c(9,10)]

dimnames(Eins)[[2]]<-c("Distance", "OD")
dimnames(Zwei)[[2]]<-c("Distance", "OD")
dimnames(Drei)[[2]]<-c("Distance", "OD")
dimnames(Vier)[[2]]<-c("Distance", "OD")
dimnames(Funf)[[2]]<-c("Distance", "OD")

gplot1 <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=Eins, mapping=aes(x=Distance, y=OD, col="red"))+
  geom_line(data=Zwei, mapping=aes(x=Distance, y=OD, col="blue"))+
  geom_line(data=Drei, mapping=aes(x=Distance, y=OD, col="orange"))+
  geom_line(data=Vier, mapping=aes(x=Distance, y=OD, col="cyan"))+
  geom_line(data=Funf, mapping=aes(x=Distance, y=OD, col="brown"))+
  scale_color_identity()

print(gplot1)

Eins$Distance <- Eins$Distance+0
Zwei$Distance <- Zwei$Distance+0
Drei$Distance <- Drei$Distance+5
Vier$Distance <- Vier$Distance+5
Funf$Distance <- Funf$Distance+15

gplot2 <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=Eins, mapping=aes(x=Distance, y=OD, col="red"))+
  geom_line(data=Zwei, mapping=aes(x=Distance, y=OD, col="blue"))+
  geom_line(data=Drei, mapping=aes(x=Distance, y=OD, col="orange"))+
  geom_line(data=Vier, mapping=aes(x=Distance, y=OD, col="cyan"))+
  geom_line(data=Funf, mapping=aes(x=Distance, y=OD, col="brown"))+
  scale_color_identity()

print(gplot2)

Gesamt <- merge(Eins,Zwei,all=T, by="Distance")
Gesamt <- merge(Gesamt,Drei,all=T, by="Distance")
Gesamt <- merge(Gesamt,Vier,all=T, by="Distance")
Gesamt <- merge(Gesamt,Funf,all=T, by="Distance")

Gesamt$Mittel <- apply(Gesamt[,c(2:length(Gesamt))], 1, mean,na.rm=T)
Gesamt <- Gesamt[,c("Distance","Mittel")]

plot2 <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=Gesamt, mapping=aes(x=Distance, y=Mittel))
print(plot2)

write.csv(Gesamt, "Gesamt.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends entirely on how you want to measure the fit between the curves. The data seem to approximately follow a parabola. Fitting a quadratic curve to each data set and then adjusting the Distance so that they peak at the same point would be a reasonable solution:

```
X1 <- lm(OD~poly(Distance, 2, raw=TRUE), Eins)
Max1 <- -coef(X1)[2]/(2 * coef(X1)[3])

X2 <- lm(OD~poly(Distance, 2, raw=TRUE), Zwei)
Max2 <- -coef(X2)[2]/(2 * coef(X2)[3])

X3 <- lm(OD~poly(Distance, 2, raw=TRUE), Drei)
Max3 <- -coef(X3)[2]/(2 * coef(X3)[3])

X4 <- lm(OD~poly(Distance, 2, raw=TRUE), Vier)
Max4 <- -coef(X4)[2]/(2 * coef(X4)[3])

X5 <- lm(OD~poly(Distance, 2, raw=TRUE), Funf)
Max5 <- -coef(X5)[2]/(2 * coef(X5)[3])

Max1 - unname(c(Max2, Max3, Max4, Max5))
# [1]  3.014317  7.404989  8.539124 14.514378
```

Using those coefficients to modify The distances would give:

```
Eins$Distance <- Eins$Distance
Zwei$Distance <- Zwei$Distance + 3
Drei$Distance <- Drei$Distance + 7.4
Vier$Distance <- Vier$Distance + 8.5
Funf$Distance <- Funf$Distance + 14.5

gplot2 <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=Eins, mapping=aes(x=Distance, y=OD, col="red"))+
  geom_line(data=Zwei, mapping=aes(x=Distance, y=OD, col="blue"))+
  geom_line(data=Drei, mapping=aes(x=Distance, y=OD, col="orange"))+
  geom_line(data=Vier, mapping=aes(x=Distance, y=OD, col="cyan"))+
  geom_line(data=Funf, mapping=aes(x=Distance, y=OD, col="brown"))+
  scale_color_identity()

print(gplot2)
```

[image: Plots]

Comment: Thank you sir. This is exactly what I was searching for! :)

Comment: @Cosis94 Good to know it solved your problem. On behalf of dcarlson, please consider accepting the answer and/or granting points as recognition of their work which increases their reputation in the system (you can do this from the top left of the answer).

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that!